# BCP export more rows per batch to file (queryout)

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am using Windows 10 and running this straight from the command prompt (Administrator). Is there a way to change the row count being output to a text file?

```
BCP "SELECT * FROM db.dbo.table WHERE row_date = '2016-10-11'" queryout "C:/Users/table.csv" -t, -c -S "servername" -T

1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 1000
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 2000
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 3000
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 4000
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 5000
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 6000


12136 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
```

Then I tried -b 5000 and -b10000:

```
BCP "SELECT * FROM db.dbo.table WHERE row_date = '2016-10-11'" queryout "C:/Users/table.csv" -t, -c -b 5000 -S "servername" -T
```

But it still outputs 1000 rows. I tried to increase the packet size with -a but that didn't impact it at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> -b batch_size Specifies the number of rows per batch of imported data. [[BOL]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

The parameter changes import batch size only. I'm not aware of anyway to change the export row count reporting.

Comment: Sad, but apparently true. "-b batch_size Specifies the number of rows per batch of imported data." http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16